# Why does Rails I18n.t wrap my translation in a paragraph?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

In my Rails 4 application I use a helper class to generate a JSON tree for a UI element. Here is a simplified version of the class:

```
class TaxonomyTree
    def initialize(root_node)
        @root_node = root_node
        @deprecation_marker = t(:deprecated)
    end

    # Method for generating the JSON tree which use @deprecation_marker ...
end
```

The corresponding entry in my locale looks like this:

```
en:
    deprecated: deprecated
```

For some reason, after the an instance is initialized, @deprecation_marker contains `<p>deprecated</p>` instead of the expected `deprecated`. Where does the `<p>` come from? And how can I get rid of it?

PS: I would guess that it has to do with the fact that the class is instantiated from a view (I know this is not optimal). But still, when would such a behavior ever be desirable?

Comment: Where does you t-method come from? ActionView's TranslationHelper or I18n?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, you pointed me in the right direction. As it turned out, t referred to neither of those you mentioned but instead to Redcloth's textilize, which also has a "t" alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To all of those facing a similar problem, in my case it was caused by the Redcloth gem, which also defines a t alias for `ER::Util#textilize`. Therefore, my call to `t(:deprecated)` did not actually use `I18n.t`.

The workaround is simple, instead of `t(:deprecated)` I now use `I18n.t(:deprecated)`.